# Check If True in a certain time frame | Pinescript V5

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading

My pine script code has the following problem

```
working version 1:
buy_signal = condition1

working version 2:
buy_signal = condition1

working version 3:
buy_signal = condition1 or condition2
```

*but with the following it doesn't generate any trades...*

The only one not working is:

```
buy_signal = condition1 and condition2
```

This must be due to the different release dates of the information, which means that they are not true at the same time.

That's why I need a function/ Workaround to check if a condition is true in a certain time frame

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ta.barssince()` to see when your condition was `true`. Then use that as a condition.

> **ta.barssince()**
>
> *Counts the number of bars since the last time the condition was true.*

```
ta.barssince(condition) → series int
```

Something like this:

```
barssince_cond1 = ta.barssince(condition1)
barssince_cond2 = ta.barssince(condition2)

buy_signal = false

buy_signal := if (condition1 and condition2)  // If both conditions are true on the same bar, then buy
    true
else if (condition1)  // If only the condition1 is true, check when was the last time condition2 was true
    if (barssince_cond2 > 0) and (barssince_cond2 < 5)  // Was it true within the last 5 bars? Then buy
        true
else if (condition2)  // If only the condition2 is true, check when was the last time condition1 was true
    if (barssince_cond1 > 0) and (barssince_cond1 < 5)  // Was it true within the last 5 bars? Then buy
        true
```